# HardwareId limit does not seem to match documentation limitation

Tags: azure-digital-twins

Is there a way to set up a HardwareId longer than 32 characters? 
Is that limit something that will disappear/be increased later on?

Hardware id needs to match the header in the message according to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/concepts-device-ingress#device-to-cloud-message and there it seems that the length limit is 72.

Tried in the preview version of Azure Digital Twin.

POST to create a space with a HardwareID longer than 32 characters

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "typeId": 2,
    "hardwareId": "UUID-C1267664F59144D489F35E8335553D4B",
    "spaceId": "55af6869-097c-4010-9f5f-c882528b41aa"
}
```

The REST call returns error:

{
    "error": {
        "code": "400.600.000.000",
        "message": "Invalid value for parameter(s): 'data.HardwareId'"
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you are linking to is talking about **Sensor hardware Id**. So the Sensor Hardware Id max length is 72 you can confirm that on your [Digital Twins Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-use-swagger). Swagger it's a tool to assist with development and testing calls made to the Azure Digital Twins Management APIs.

In the other hand **Device hardware Id** max length is 36 characters my source for this is also the Digital Twins Swagger.

**Devices** are attached to a space. They are entities (physical or virtual) that manage a number of sensors. For example, a device could be a user’s phone, a Raspberry Pi sensor pod, Lora gateway, etc.

**Sensors** are attached to a device and a space. They record values. For example: battery level, temperature, noise, motion, etc.

If you believe that the **Device hardware Id** max length should be greater than 36 characters please create an entry in the [Azure Digital Twins User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/916621-azure-digital-twins) site. This way other users can upvote your proposal.